# Detect cpu slat capability when hypervisor is running

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

Hyper-v 2016 TP now requires that you have a [processor with SLAT capabilities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608570.aspx).

Is there a method to find the if this is on a CPU without looking up the CPU docs and verifying?

When I run the command

```
Get-CimInstance win32_processor | Select-Object -Property Name, SecondLevelAddressTranslationExtensions
```

I get this output claiming that I don't have SLAT support, but everything I have read tells me that anything with E5500 or above should be slat capable.

```
Name                                            SecondLevelAddressTranslationExtensions
----                                            ---------------------------------------
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz                                   False
```

Since the **hypervisor is running** on the system though, I am probably not getting a real view of things.

Is there any method to get the actual capabilities on a **running hyper-v system**?

Comment: Sorry about that - I deleted my answer about coreinfo.exe... maybe someone will have a better answer...

Comment: @RyanRies You didn't really need to delete it.  I am sure it would have been useful to someone else who found this question via the Google's.  I was just adding the comment, so you understood why I wasn't ticking the accept.